# Issue with Image View and onClickListener

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

Im new to android programming and I am trying to build an app with imageviews that open up a new activity for each image view clicked with an image view of their own. so far i have made my main activity and put 4 image views on it all below each other with constraints. all works fine in the sense of when i open the app, the image views are laid out how they should be and i can click on imageview1, then 2, then 3, then 4 and then any of them. but if i open the app and try to click on imageview 2 first or imageview 3 for example, or imageview 4 then it doesn't work. I have to start at 1 and then go on to 2 and then 3 and 4 and then finally i can navigate freely. How can I fix this? I have posted my main activity java file below before. Any help would be appreciated.

```
package com.ntq.ntqapp;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;



public class MainActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView ts;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);


    ts  = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ts1);
    ts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity1.this, imageView1.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);


     ts = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ts2);
     ts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
         public void onClick(View view) {
             Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity1.this, imageView2.class);
             startActivity(myIntent);

     ts = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ts3);
     ts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           public void onClick(View view) {
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity1.this, imageView3.class);
           startActivity(myIntent);

     ts = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ts4);
     ts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View view) {
              Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), imageView4.class);
           startActivity(myIntent);


         }

         }
         );
        }}
         );
        }});}});}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.  First problem is your end brackets are in the wrong location.  The second problem is you are using the same variable.  Here is the code corrected:

```
package com.ntq.ntqapp;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;



public class MainActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView ts1;
    private ImageView ts2;
    private ImageView ts3;
    private ImageView ts4;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);

        ts1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ts1);
        ts1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity1.this,
                                             imageView1.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });

        ts2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ts2);
        ts2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity1.this,
                                             imageView2.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        ts3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ts3);
        ts3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity1.this,
                                             imageView3.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        ts4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ts4);
        ts4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                                             imageView4.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Bro...I LOVE YOU. it was those definitely something with the brackets now it works how it should. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same variable name ts for all the views.

Change to ts1, ts2, ts3, ts4.

Also there are some issues with closing parentheses.

You need to close the parentheses for the onClick method, for the inner classes and for the outer method each time.

```
ts1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ts1);
ts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity1.this, imageView1.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    } //you are missing this
}); //and this

// Notice how I change the variable name to ts2 here...
ts2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ts2);
//rinse and repeat...
```

Comment: this would work i guess but i tried tims answer above and it works now. thank you for the help though :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same variable for all the views: `private ImageView ts`
Use 4 different variables (ts1, ts2...) that will fix your sequence issue !!

Comment: yeah i tried using ts1, ts2, ts3, ts4 before but it reacted the same . i could click first image view then 2nd then 3rd then 4th then any of them but if try to click 2, 3rd or 4th imageview first i cant :S

Comment: You have this ` ts = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ts2)` change it to  ` ts2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ts2)`.. simialrly for the rest as well